# Varying citation format style

Tags: bibtex, citing, acm

**Summary**: I'm trying to figure out how to switch between `[author-last-name et al. year]` and `author-last-name [year]` formatting using the ACM-Reference-Format-Journals format.

**Details**:

I'm using the [ACM Small Standard Format](http://www.acm.org/publications/latex_style/v2-acmsmall.zip) and I noticed a paper that sometime has references with [Author year] in brackets and sometimes just the year.  What I want to do is probably clearer looking at an example from another paper:

[image]

The `Java programs[Kazi and Lilja 2000]` citation uses the "[Author year]" style, while `Bhowmik and Franklin [2002]` uses the "Author [year]" style.

I looked at the `ACM-Reference-Format-Journals.bst` and saw that the comments seem to indicate different citation formation options exist.  But it's not clear to me how to select the format I want for various differnt `cite{...}` citations in my latex file.  So my question is how can I pick between two different formats.

```
%   Citation format: [author-last-name year]
%             [author-last-name and author-last-name year]
%             [author-last-name, author-last-name, and author-last-name year]
%             [author-last-name et al. year]
%             [author-last-name]
%             author-last-name [year]
%             [author-last-name and author-last-name]
%             [author-last-name et al.]
%             [year] or [year,year]
%             year or year,year
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the documentation `acmsmall-guide.pdf` (page 1:11):

[image]

So you need to use `\citeN` or `\citeyear`. A little example:

```
\documentclass[prodmode,acmtecs]{acmsmall}

\acmVolume{9}
\acmNumber{4}
\acmArticle{39}
\acmYear{2010}
\acmMonth{3}

\begin{document}

\cite{Cohen07}

\citeN{Cohen07}

\bibliographystyle{ACM-Reference-Format-Journals}
\bibliography{acmsmall-sample-bibfile}

\end{document}
```

[image]