# Varying in text citations in the ACM sig-alternate style

Tags: citing, acm

The ACM [sig-alternate style guide states](http://www.acm.org/sigs/publications/sig-alternate.pdf):

> This article shows only the plainest form of the citation command,
>   using \cite. This is what is stipulated in the SIGS style
>   specifications. No other citation format is en- dorsed or supported.

Is there a way to automate the use of other styles (such as `\citeN` [as in the [`acmsmall`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/231197) style] or other variations `\citep`, `\citet` etc. as per the `natbib` package)?

Comment: Indeed, I would not read this passage either as saying that no commands for generating citation call-outs other than `\cite` are permitted. In my view, the authors do wish to make clear that they strongly prefer use of the simplest command, ie., `\cite`. Furthermore, they do not wish to take sides in fruitless debates over which citation management package (`cite` vs `natbib`, anyone?) is better. It's quite clear, though, that the citation call-outs must be numeric and must be encased in square brackets.

Comment: I strongly suspect that this is exactly the type of argumentative conversation that the authors were refusing to engage in. If you need or want to pursue this further, you should contact the appropriate editorial office(s) and ask what kind of leeway, if any, may be available in terms of the format of citation call-outs.